# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE not printing when EXECUTE IMMEDIATE executed

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am checking Oracle DB status and when its not open,  run open command from plsql as below and check status after restart. when even the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter database open'` executed, the output from furher DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE not getting printed. I have SET SERVEROUTPUT ON and SET TERM ON at the begining of the script.

```
begin
  select INST_ID into l_inst_id from gv$instance where instance_name=l_instname;
  select open_mode,name into l_mode,l_dbname from gv$database where inst_id=l_inst_id;
  select inst_id,STATUS,instance_name into l_inst,l_status,l_instname from gv$instance where inst_id=l_inst_id; 
if (l_mode <> 'READ WRITE') then
    if (l_mode like '%MOUNT%') then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ERROR: DB instance : '|| l_instname || ' is not OPEN,current status is ' || l_mode );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Starting the Database instance : ' || l_instname );
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter database open';
    end if; 
    select open_mode  into l_fmode  from gv$database where inst_id=l_inst_id;
    if (l_fmode <> 'READ WRITE') then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ERROR: DB instance : '|| l_instname || ' open attempted but failed. Engage DBA to review the issue');
        else
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Database open command completed succefully, current DB instance status fmode: ' || l_fmode);
        end if;
else
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Status of DB instance '|| l_instname || ' is ' || l_mode || ', No action requried ' );
END IF;
end;
/
```

Comment: Your if statement doesn't looks correct logically -   if (l_fmode = 'READ WRITE') then - should be reversed i.e. else part should be in then

Comment: I edited it. Do you know the reason for dbms not printing output.

Comment: This is what I believe might be the cause  - DBMS_OUTPUT is a buffered output and is read after the procedure or code is complete (all at once). In case alter database open, I believe it clears the buffers and hence nothing to output.

Comment: Instead of pl/sql block and dbms_output, I would suggest to use a simple sqlplus script with conditional execution and variables : http://orasql.org/2013/04/17/sqlplus-tips-4-branching-execution/

Comment: when condition  l_mode like '%MOUNT%' is met ,script not even printing the two DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE statements before EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Does this code even work, regardless of whether dbms_output is writing anything? The code doesn't run in sqlplus: you're trying to execute code against a database that *isn't open* to run code, by definition. On top of that, DBMS_OUTPUT writes to a memory buffer *in the database*, not directly to the console. If there's no open database, then there's no buffer to write output to, by definition. I think that the only way this code would do anything is if the database was *already* open.

Answer (score 0):

I had to declare a bunch of variables and set one of them...but I got DBMS_OUTPUT to print.

```
clear screen
set serveroutput on
declare
 l_inst_id integer;
 l_inst integer;
 l_mode varchar2(30);
 l_dbname varchar2(30);
 l_instname varchar2(30) := 'orclcdb';
 l_status varchar2(30);
 l_fmode varchar2(30);
begin
  select INST_ID into l_inst_id from gv$instance where instance_name=l_instname;
  select open_mode,name into l_mode,l_dbname from gv$database where inst_id=l_inst_id;
  select inst_id,STATUS,instance_name into l_inst,l_status,l_instname from gv$instance where inst_id=l_inst_id; 
if (l_mode <> 'READ WRITE') then
    if (l_mode like '%MOUNT%') then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ERROR: DB instance : '|| l_instname || ' is not OPEN,current status is ' || l_mode );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Starting the Database instance : ' || l_instname );
     --   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter database open';
    end if; 
    select open_mode  into l_fmode  from gv$database where inst_id=l_inst_id;
    if (l_fmode <> 'READ WRITE') then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ERROR: DB instance : '|| l_instname || ' open attempted but failed. Engage DBA to review the issue');
        else
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Database open command completed succefully, current DB instance status fmode: ' || l_fmode);
        end if;
else
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Status of DB instance '|| l_instname || ' is ' || l_mode || ', No action requried ' );
END IF;
end;
/
```

I commented out the 'alter database open' - we're here to test DBMS_OUTPUT, not alter the state of my database.

Running in SQL Developer -

[image]

Comment: I too did this earlier. But I want to run alter command if DB not open then check the status. Any workaround to get this done. I added DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (500000); after alter command but did not work.

Comment: when condition l_mode like '%MOUNT%' is met ,script not even printing the two DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE statements before EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Can a PL/SQL construct like this even run in a database that - by definition/requirement - *isn't open*? wouldn't DBMS_PUTPUT require an open database to write to its memory buffer? Is a `MOUNT` state enough?

Comment: I think that's a great question @pmdba

Comment: If you're database is MOUNTed, then DBMS_OUTPUT will still work, see https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/993838/will-pl-sql-statements-work-on-mount-mode